# Как использовать выражение "засыпать кого чем"?

Tags: перевод

Как можно правильно использовать выражение засыпать кого чем? Можно сказать меня засыпали работой? Меня засыпали должностей?

Спасибо за помощь

Comment: (1) *"Меня засыпали должностей"* is an ungrammatical sentence (because of *должность* setted to the wrong case, there must be Instrumental, Должность(Ins,pl)=Должностями) and, it is incomprehensible too. You probably mean a noun *обязанность* instead of *должность.* Then the right expression will be *"Меня засы́пали обязанностями"* (2) just a side note, there is 2 verbs, засыпа́ть=to fall asleep & засы́пать="to rain of something":a large number of things falling or moving through the air together

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Глагол "**зас*ы*пали**" большей частью применяется (в прямом и переносном смысле) с материалами, которые состоят из большого количества маленьких частиц, то есть материалами, которые можно "с**ы**пать".  Песок, например, можно сыпать.  Муку.  Снег.  Ну а *воду*, например, сыпать затруднительно, её обычно **льют**.

Устойчивыми сочетаниями при переносном смысле являются "**засыпать вопросами**", "**засыпать упрёками**", "**засыпать делами**".  "*Засыпать работой*" сказать-то можно и, наверное, поймут, причём правильно, но это идиомой не является.

Чаще говорят "**завалили работой**".

---

С "должностей" - я не понял, что Вы хотели сказать...  Добавлю, если Вы поподробнее (или иными словами) объясните.

Answer (score 1):

(как дополнение)

*В контексте* **работы** или **должности** слово иногда *можно* употребить. **Завалить заявками** (заказами) на какую-либо **работу** - здесь для переносного смысла используется распространённая аналогия с сыпучими веществами (*множество мелких сущностей*).

Видимо, иначе работает другое, неформальное значение слова: **засЫпать** (завалить) **на экзамене** (*на собеседовании, аттестации на **должность*** и т. п.) - подразумевается, что те, от кого при формальной процедуре зависит оценка, допуск к конкурсной должности, отбор при кастинге и т. п. *умышленно* задавали сложные *вопросы* в интересах получения отрицательного результата. Трудно точно сказать, связано ли такое выражение с устойчивым "*засыпать вопросами*" или здесь действует скрытая аналогия с "*похоронить (буквально, **засыпав** землёй)*", поскольку синонимично этому столь же неформальное "завалить". Соответственно, возможна ситуация "меня **засыпали** при аттестации на такую-то **должность**". "*Засыпать (провалить) на экзамене*" можно найти напр. в Толковом словаре словаре Ожегова:

[https://поискслов.рф/wd/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%D1%80%D1%84/wd/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)